# How to limit the impact of Geometry proximity node?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I use Geometry proximity to create steps, but as soon as two stairs are close to each other, they start to mix, I think it’s possible to limit using ID Target, but I don’t know how to do it.[image]

[image]

Comment: It's  unclear why you are using proximity here at all? Can you please describe your strategy more fully? Usually you would simply instance steps on the curve.. can you describe why you have chosen this method

Comment: Plug the *Distance* into a *Compare* node

Comment: @quellenform .. if you can figure out what's going on, I can withdraw my comment :)

Comment: @RobinBetts I have no idea either so I just guessed in the dark...

Comment: @RobinBetts I am making steps that will change their size along with the size of the polygon on which they are created
It's just that this decision came to my mind, if it can be done differently, then I will be glad to advice.
I have attached a blend file in which you can understand the problem in more detail

Comment: i would recommend providing 2 examples (4 pics) with before (your polygons) and after (with steps how it should look like) so that we have an idea what you wanna achieve. thx.

Comment: @Chris I can take screenshots, but I thought the attached blend file would be more informative, stairs have already been made there, and all I want is that they don't stick together when they are close to each other

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I was able to solve the problem by just coming up with a new combination of nodes